# Setting src property for img tag using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some images in my asp.net mvc4 view page set initialy like below:

```
<img id="MyImage-1-Img" src="~/images/blank.png">

<img id="MyImage-2-Img" src="~/images/blank.png">

<img id="MyImage-3-Img" src="~/images/blank.png">
```

and in a certain moment in my code, from the view and using jquery I want to change the image for one of them so I perform following action:

```
function (id)
{
    $('#MyImage-' + id + '-Img').prop("src", @Url.Content("~/images/SomeImage.png"));
}
```

but in runtime I get an error saying:

```
Syntax error in regular expression
```

It seems it is parsed as:

```
 $('#' + elemId + '-Img').prop("src", /images/Passed.png);
```

so the error is on the value passed to prop method, that is, @Url.Content("~/images/SomeImage.png") that returns /images/Passed.png

My images folder is in the root \images and the code (line) above indicated from which line is executed is \Views\Test folder.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing `""` quotation marks

```
 $('#MyImage-' + id + '-Img').prop("src", '@Url.Content("~/images/SomeImage.png")');
```

Comment: You have a problem with nesting quotes inside quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to quote the source!

```
.prop("src", '@Url.Content("~/images/SomeImage.png")');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the .attr() method:

```
function (id)
{
    $('#MyImage-' + id + '-Img').attr("src", "images/SomeImage.png");
}
```